# Interpreting SMART on new Seagate drive

Tags: hard-drive, smart

After a long time using WD disks which always reported everything as OK (*) I recently purchased a Seagate ST4000VN006. It passed its long and conveyance tests. I then moved a a couple of Logical Volumes onto it (heavy write access), and now SMART is showing this:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   081   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       129019136
    ...
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   065   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       3024335
```

Others all normalized 100 or otherwise as expected. The Raw values are clearly in need of decoding rather than directly useful. The Raw Read Error Rate is going up and down depending on drive activity levels.

Can anybody with experience of recent Seagate drives tell me whether this is cause for concern with a brand new drive? Or does Seagate simply normalize its raw values differently (more honestly? *) than WD, and nothing to worry about unless these numbers were to dip below their threshold values in future?

(*) the oldest WD drive has started making a whining noise. After nearly 10 years powered up, it's reasonable that its bearings may be getting tired. But SMART not noticing? In passing, WD's "Red" fiasco (selling Shingled drives under their "NAS" brand) is the reason I have switched vendor. Another "New Coke"?

Comment: See https://www.disktuna.com/big-scary-raw-s-m-a-r-t-values-arent-always-bad-news/ and http://www.users.on.net/~fzabkar/HDD/Seagate_SER_RRER_HEC.html

Comment: The only values that matter for determining hardware failure are `Offline_Uncorrectable` and `Reallocated Sectors`, and when a hardware error occurs, you'll also see it below the attribute values and above the self-test info _(Seek and Read error rates are software-based)_

Comment: JW0914, no, pending sectors is more important than reallocated sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joep van Steen's comment, lots of useful Seagate-specific info [here](http://www.users.on.net/%7Efzabkar/HDD/Seagate_SER_RRER_HEC.html)

Seek Error Rate and Read error rate are normalized logarithmically. SER of 60 is one seek error per million. RRER of 64 is between 10^5 (70) and 10^6 (60) errors per 10^12 bits.

Looks like nothing to worry about, but useful to know that any slow downwards drift is not really so slow. A change of 10 in the normalized value means it has become ten times worse. Change of 20, a hundred times worse!